# How to make Liberation Sans the default font in LO Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice Writer defaults to Liberation Serif. How do I make it default to Liberation Sans instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Writer - Basic Fonts

[image]

Comment: more and more documents are only read on screen. Thus, sans should replace serif as default by Libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

in libreoffice writer go to tools.. options. Select the options for libreoffice writer. Here you have options for the default font. you can select the font for different types of paragraphs